# Is it true that $\sin(\theta) e^{R\cos(\theta)} - \sin\big(\theta + R \sin(\theta)\big) > 0$ here?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inequality

Define the function:
$$
g(R,\theta) = \sin(\theta) e^{R\cos(\theta)} - \sin\big(\theta + R \sin(\theta)\big)
$$

For $\theta \in \big[ 0 , \frac{\pi}{2} \big)$ and $R \gg 2 \pi$, is it true that $g(R,\theta) > 0$?

I have been playing around with Mathematica, and it seems to be the case. I can't find a way to prove this more formally.

**My Attempt:** For $\theta \in \big[ 0 , \frac{\pi}{2} \big)$ we have $0 \leq \sin(\theta) < 1$. It would then *seem* that;
$$
\sin(\theta) e^{R\cos(\theta)} \gg \sin\big(\theta + R \sin(\theta)\big)
$$ on this interval. However, my worry is that for very small values of $\theta$ we might have $\sin(\theta) e^{R\cos(\theta)} < \sin\big(\theta + R \sin(\theta)\big)$. Does anyone have any thoughts?

EDIT: It would seem that $g(0, R) = 0$, so I should rather say $g(R,\theta) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$x:=R\cos\theta>0,\quad y:=R\sin\theta\geq0\ .$$
We then can express $g$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ as follows:
$$\eqalign{\hat g(x,y)&={y\> e^x\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-{y\cos y+x\sin y\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cr&=
{y\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\biggl((e^x-1-x)+(1-\cos y)+x(1-{\rm sinc}\,y)\biggr)\ .\cr}$$Here the three terms appearing in the large parenthesis on the RHS are all $\geq0$.