# bounds of module of $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-z}}$

Tags: calculus

Let $R$ be a positive real number such that $R \not \in (2 \mathbb{Z} + 1) \pi$.

I would like to prove that the values taken by the function
$$  f_R(\theta)
 =
 \dfrac{1}{1 + 2 e^{- R \cos \theta} \cos (R \sin \theta) + e^{-2 R \cos \theta}}
$$ are between
$$ \left [
   \dfrac{e^R}{4 \cosh^2 \dfrac{R}{2}}
   ,
   \dfrac{1}{4 \cos^2 \dfrac{R}{2}}
 \right ]
 \ .
$$

Of course, this function is an even one and $2\pi$-periodic.

I can easily prove that it is a decreasing function over $\left [ \dfrac{\pi}{2} ; \pi \right ]$ from $\dfrac{1}{4 \cos^2 \dfrac{R}{2}}$ to $\dfrac{e^{-R}}{4 \cosh^2 \dfrac{R}{2}}$
(See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587161/is-it-true-that-sin-theta-er-cos-theta-sin-big-theta-r-sin-thet)
where the discussed quantity is related to the numerator of the derivative of $f_R$, for a proof)

**Question:** Is anyone able to prove that $f_R$ is increasing over
$\left [ 0 ; \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right ]$ ?

**Edit:** Since the proposed bounds are incorrect, is anyone able to gives and prove a correct upper bound of $f_R$ on $\left [ 0 ; \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right ]$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+e^z}=\frac{e^{-z/2}}{e^{-z/2}+e^{z/2}}=\frac12\frac{e^{-z/2}}{\cosh z/2}$

Comment: I do not understand how this prove that $f_R$ is an increassing function over $\left [ 0 ; \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right ]$... Could you, please, gives more details?

Comment: It is quite easy to show the lower bound of $f_R$:
$f_R(\theta) \geq \dfrac{1}{1 + 2 e^{-R \cos \theta} + e^{-2 R \cos \theta}}
                     = \dfrac{1}{(1 + e^{- R \cos \theta})^2}
                     \geq \dfrac{1}{(1 + e^{-R})^2}
                     = \dfrac{e^R}{4 \cosh^2 \dfrac{R}{2}}
$.
But, this idea does not givs the upper bound, nor the increassing caracter of $f_R$ over $\left [ 0 ; \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right ]$.

Comment: Oups... Last comment is false... because last inequalities is false!!! Nevertheless, the conjectured bounds o the question seems to be right

Answer (score 1):

The function $f_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is not an increassing function...:

$f_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is first increassing from $\dfrac{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{4 \cosh^2(\frac{\pi}{4})} \approx 0.685$ to $0.718$, $\theta \in \left [ 0 ; \approx 0.944 \right ]$, and then is decreassing to $\dfrac{1}{2}$ on $\left [\approx 0.944 ; \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right ]$ (and even on $[\approx 0.944 ; \pi]$).

[Here is the graph of $f_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg84F.png)

Therefore, the announced upper bound is false...